# SQL to LINQ INNER JOIN, WHERE statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to convert a SQL statement to LINQ. I've converted a few but I can't figure out this one.

```
SELECT name FROM people p 
INNER JOIN 
careers c on p.SSN = c.SSN 
WHERE 
p.City = "new york" AND c.occupation = "engineer"
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error, or ??? Is "name" found in both tables?

Comment: EF core doesn't want to return a single column using SQL raw, have to do it in LINQ. I have no idea why.

Comment: Show the class model. With a navigation property this is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
List<string> peopleList = new List<string>();

peopleList = (from p in _context.people
              join c in _context.Careers on p.SSN equals c.SSN
              where (p.city == "new york") && (c.occupation == "Engineer")
              select p.name
             ).ToList();
```